# JasperReport and text fields

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Good day boys and girls;

I wanted to know if possible, pass a text field iReport with another textfield containing. I'm trying but not working. When print the second field as a text and not interpreted as such

E.G.

"\"Name of the pet is :\" + $F{pet}.getName()"

Comment: You can set the same expression for both text fields. Please post your sample for better understanding your needs

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need to set text field's value with value from another text field? I mean that you can set any expression for one or several text fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the slashes, but perhaps this is what you are looking for?

"Name of the pet is :" + $F{pet}